# wordpress bootstrap. No flowing to the right

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So, after a few bootstrap tuts, decided to try mixing it up with wordpress. A whole bunch of questions there, but my main concern right now is, why isn't angies list image moving to the right? I did float:right in css, i did pull-right class, i even did margin-left:99%... it's still there. WHY?
Any other notes are appreciated as well :)
you can see the whole thing here
http://soloveich.com/

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid>

<div class="row-fluid" id="heady">
    <div class="span4"><div id="sign"></div></div>

     <div class="span4" id="menubg">
         <nav class="navbar">
       <div class="navbar-inner">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
       </div> 
      </nav>       
     </div>

     <div class="span4" class="pull-right"><div id="angies"><img src="http://www.soloveich.com/wp-content/themes/Yellow-sign/images/angies.png"></div>
     <div id="lic">
        <ul id="licen">
          <li>Phone# (555)555-5555</li>
          <li>Lic# 7778899</li>
          <li>Bond# 111223344</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

and the css

```
#heady {
background-color: #727272;
Height:370px;
}

#sign{
background-image: url(images/sign.png);
height: 334px;
width: 334px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

#menubg {
font-family:  'Contrail One', cursive;
font-weight: 200;
font-size: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
margin-top:130px;
}

#angies {
margin-top: 20px;
float: right;
margin-left: 99%;
}
```

Comment: It's on the right for me. But if you resize your browser, it goes to the left. I think that's part of using container-fluid...it's a fluid container so if the browser resizes then the floats go to the next "line" i.e. left

Comment: My bad. I didn't explain it correctly. I'm trying to put it to the very right of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to have your `#angies` to the very right of your page do the following:

```
#angies{
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:20px;
  right:0px;
}
```

Long story short: you will force your element to break out of the flow in an absolute position at 0px from your right.

Also as I was browsing to the source of the page using developer tools in Chrome I realized that you are not embedding correctly the bootstrap javascript. See the last script tag before your ending `</body>` tag. You forgot to include the path to the template which is mandatory in Wordpress when you are including javascript files. That line of code should look like this:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

instead of just this:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```